# How to replace spaces in label tag with <br>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I replace all spaces in <label> tag with <br>?
For example I have:

```
<label>Some text here</label>
```

And change it to:

```
<label>Some<br>text<br>here</label>
```

I try to use this code:

```
$('.form-group label').html().replace(' ', '<br>');
```

But it didn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method with a callback function. And for replacing all the space use regex with global falg in [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```js
$('label').html(function(i, oldHTML) {
  return oldHTML.replace(/\s+/g, '<br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Some text here</label>
```

Comment: @VladIvanov :  glad to help you

Comment: replace **all** spaces - only does the first

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the html this will probably work:

```
$('.form-group label').html($('.form-group label').html().replace(' ', '<br>'));
```